# How to remove advertising redirection?

Tags: .htaccess

I am using a url shortner script.
it has advertising / link rules.

but i dont want short link to redirect on ad link.
in admin panel there is no option to remove ad support. 
please have a look [beurl.in](http://beurl.in)

here is my htaccess file code.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

FileETag none
ServerSignature Off

Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6})$ links/?to=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,9})/banner/(.*)$ links/?uid=$1&adt=2&url=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,9})/(.*)$ links/?uid=$1&adt=1&url=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Use a URL shortener that doesn't force you to use ads, like [goo.gl](http://goo.gl) or [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com).

Answer (score 1):

The business model of that page is based on the ads they show you. Trying to subvert that is at least unethical more likely against their terms of service (though hard to check since the link is down). 
If you really want short urls and don't want the ads why not use a different provider like [goo.gl](http://goo.gl)? They offer the same service for free (i.e. you don't pay by seeing ads).